# Why is Java removeAll method in List removing duplicate items?

Tags: java

```
@Test
public void test4() {

    List<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();

    test.add("A");
    test.add("B");
    test.add("C");
    test.add("C");

    System.out.println("full list ...." );

    for (String s : test) {

        System.out.println(s);
    }

    System.out.println("tmp list ...." );

    List<String> tmp = test.subList( 0, 1) ;

    for (String s : tmp) {

        System.out.println(s);
    }

    System.out.println("after removing tmp ...." );

    test.removeAll( tmp );

    for (String s : test) {

        System.out.println(s);
    }

}
```

The above code outputs

```
full list ....
A
B
C
C
tmp list ....
A
after removing tmp ....
B
C
C
```

If 
`List<String> tmp = test.subList( 0, 2) ;`

Then the output is

```
full list ....
A
B
C
C
tmp list ....
A
B
after removing tmp ....
C
```

Why is there only a single "C" in the list?

Comment: see the java documentation on [removeAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection))

Comment: @Aominè , *Removes all of this collection's elements that are also contained in the specified collection (optional operation). After this call returns, this collection will contain no elements in common with the specified collection.* - That doesn't explain why one `C` is also removed when the sublist contains just `A` and `B`

Comment: Because [`subList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-) is a *view* and when you modify the underlying list, the result is unpredictable. Javadoc says: *The semantics of the list returned by this method become **undefined if the backing list (i.e., this list) is structurally modified** in any way other than via the returned list.* --- Changing `test.subList(0, 2)` to `new ArrayList<>(test.subList(0, 2))` will fix the problem, because it snapshots the view.

Comment: I would expect Java to return an error, instead of unreliable results. It works in the first case (expected result). What happens in the second case? Can you explain in detail.

Comment: @PrajwalShrestha No, I can't explain, because that's what "**undefined**" means.

Answer (score 3):

My answer was so short and got so many upvotes, so I felt a need to improve it.

When invoking `subList`, you don't get a copy. You get a view. Whenever the underlying structure of a view (in this case the original `List`) is modified, the view immediately becomes invalid. This, however, does not say anything at all about the result of using the view, other than that the result may or may not work. The behavior is *undefined*. It's like freeing memory in C. If you have a pointer to the memory you just have freed, you can still access the data. However, you have told the OS that you don't want the memory space anymore, so it can get overwritten at anytime. Same thing here. It may or may not work, because the behavior is undefined.

So what you need to do is to make a proper copy of the content. You can do this with `new ArrayList<>(test.subList(0, 2))`

Comment: can you explain in detail why it works in the first case and not in the second. I understand subList is a view.

Comment: Wether it works or not is implementation dependent. The behavior is undefined, so it may or may not work.